# Inequality of the expectation vs monotone function

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation, machine-learning, monotone-functions

I'm reading understanding machine learning and several of the latest lemmas I've studied involved this inequality which I've searched for but found no justification of whatsoever. Could anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Let $X$ be a random variable and $x' \in \mathbb{R}$ be a scalar. For all $i = 0, 1, 2,...$ denote $t_i = f(i)$ where $f$ is monotonically increasing. Then, $$\mathbb{E}[|X-x'|] \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} t_i \mathbb{P}[|X-x'| > t_{i-1}]$$

**EDIT:** I missed the initial condition $t_0 = 0$. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Hint: For every nonnegative $y$, show that $$y\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^\infty t_i\,\mathbf 1_{y>t_{i-1}},$$ provided the missing hypothesis that $t_0=0$ is added.

Comment: Shouldn't the factor in front of the probability be $t_i-t_{i-1}$ in place of $t_i$? As written, the inequality is quite un-sharp

Comment: @grand_chat The factor *could* be what you say but the point is to prove the question hence sharpness is offtopic here (commenting on comments by others without using @ might be more ontopic...).

Comment: @Did Absolutely true. (my comment was directed at the OP)

Answer (score 1):

Assume $t_0=0$. Apply the following Claim with the random variable $|X-x'|$ in place of $y$, then take expectations.

**Claim:** For every $y\ge0$,
$$y\le \sum_{i=1}^\infty (t_i-t_{i-1})I(y>t_{i-1}),\tag1$$
where $I(A)$ denotes the indicator of condition $A$, i.e., $I(A)$ is one if condition $A$ is true, zero otherwise.

**Proof:** Pick $y\ge 0$, and let $J$ be the largest $i$ such that $y>t_{i-1}$. Then $y\le t_J$. The RHS of (1)
reduces to $\sum_{i=1}^J (t_i-t_{i-1})$ which telescopes to $t_J-t_0=t_J$. But $t_J\ge y$, and we're done!

Aside: This inequality can be interpreted geometrically in view of the identity $$E(Y)=\int_{t=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y>t)\,dt,\tag2$$
valid for any nonnegative random variable $Y$. The inequality 
$$E(Y)\le\sum_{i=1}^\infty(t_i-t_{i-1})P(Y>t_{i-1})$$
is obtained by bounding the RHS of (2) by the sum of areas of rectangles over the intervals $[0, t_1]$, $[t_1, t_2]$, $[t_2,t_3]$, etc.